# How to change the slide picture when resize browser size?

Tags: html, css

I have no idea how to change image of slides when i go phone size of screen.
I used BootStrap to build my first website. it looks good on computer but the full image scale to very tiny when i change screen size, is there any idea to replace display image inside of slide when screen size changed? i need CSS code for change it, thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head></head>

<!-- Carousel
================================================== -->
<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
    <!-- Indicators -->
    <ol class="carousel-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
    </ol>
    <div class="carousel-inner" role="listbox">
        <div class="item active">
            <img class="first-slide" src="image/N-house000.jpg" alt="First slide">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="carousel-caption">
                    <h1>IntopHome LTD</h1>   
                    <p><a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="contact.html" role="button">CONTACT US</p></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</html>
```

Comment: Don't you need `body` tag?

Comment: hi, there, it has body tag, i just copy part of my code.not all.

Comment: Use media query and change height width of your image slider on different resolution or You can use bootstrap / MDL for responsive design.

Comment: I just need CSS code to auto change image of first-slide to fit small screen when you change screen size. thanks

Comment: Media query is  a CSS  code bro..

Comment: @media (max-width: 1099px){.first-slide {.....? i don't know how to code this...could you help please? thanks

Comment: what do i need to change in here? <br>@media (max-width: 1099px)
.first-slide img {
    src="newzealand.jpg";
  }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use [css media queries](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp) if you must handle it with only css,

My suggestion for you is to initialize 2 different sliders to page, which contains taller images for mobile display, in your CSS query simply hide that one for desktop and show mobile one,

CSS example:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 990px) {
    .desktop_slider{display:none; visibility: hidden;}
    .mobile_slider{display:block; visibility: visible;}
}
```